# Using GTM to add Open Graph

Tags: facebook-opengraph, google-tag-manager

Do you know, how to add open graph parameters to specific URLs on my site using Google Tag Manager? I couldn't find anywhere answer on that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at this article - the metatag insertion section may be of interest to you: https://moz.com/blog/seo-changes-using-google-tag-manager

Answer (score 1):

No unfortunately not. Unlike Google where it's become a lot better in the last 3 years at using rendered JavaScript content to pick up code generated by tag managers - Facebook sadly hasn't advanced this far + will only pick up content in the actual HTML.

See this blog post (in Dutch) for guidance: http://vlcm.be/2017/07/open-graph-metatags-google-tag-manager/

So unfortunately when it comes to OGP and Twitter Cards you'll have to add them the old fashioned way.